# HTML INPUT RANGE -- Disable submit until something changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that has three input ranges like this:

```html
<div class="form-style-5">
  <legend><span class="number">4</span> Search by Scholarship Requirements
  </legend>
  <form action="search3.php" method="post" oninput="amount1.value=rangeInput1.value; amount2.value=rangeInput2.value; amount3.value=rangeInput3.value;" target="_parent">
    <fieldset>
      Minimum SAT:
      <output for="rangeInput" name="amount1">0</output>
      <input id="rangeInput1" max="2400" min="0" name="satscore" required="" type="range" value="0">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input name="crm" type="checkbox" value="CR+M">CR+M
      <input name="crm" type="checkbox" value="CR+M+W">CR+M+W
      <br>
      <br>Minimum ACT:
      <output for="rangeInput" name="amount2">0</output>
      <input id="rangeInput2" max="36" min="0" name="actscore" required="" type="range" value="0">
      <br>
      <br>Minimum GPA:
      <output for="rangeInput" name="amount3">0</output>
      <input id="rangeInput3" max="4" min="0" name="gpascore" required="" type="range" value="0">
      <br>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH">
  </form>
</div>
```

I have the values defaulted to "0" but the issue is in some cases users will select any of the three input types but I need them to select at least one prior to submitting.

I have been racking my brain for hours and can not figure out how to do this -- can someone help?

Comment: Where's the JavaScript that you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to give each of your inputs either unique names or classes, in order to identify them in code (so you can check them individually, rather than all at once). Then, create a jQuery snippet to handle your validation;

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
  // Stop the form submitting
  e.preventDefault()

  if($("input[name='enterFieldNameHere']").val() != '0' || $("input[name='enterFieldNameHere2']").val() != '0' || $("input[name='enterFieldNameHere3']").val() != '0'){
     // At least one value isn't 0, submit the form
    return true;
  }else{
    // Tell the user the input is invalid
    alert('Please select an option');
  }
})
```

This code is untested and is only intended to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This looks good but I can't seem to get it to work -- I put it in a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/24ntequt/4/

Comment: Strangely, I also cannot get it to work in fiddle :/

Comment: Perhaps an external resource? What version of jquery?

Comment: @TomCanfarotta Good call, seems it was missing jQuery (1.11.0), it now seems to be working here https://jsfiddle.net/or172bsq/1/

Comment: Yes -- great. Works in the fiddle. This is still not working on my server -- sorry for being a pain. Can you take a look? http://meritscholarshiplist.com/wordpress/input_search4.html

Comment: Try swapping `$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e)` for  `$('form').submit(function(e){//...})` and see if you have any more luck.

Comment: No luck. Am i including jquery properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106267/discussion-between-lewis-and-tom-canfarotta).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Javascript test</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var changes = false;

    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Prevent form submission
      $("form").submit(function(event) {
        if (!changes) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });

      $("input").on('change', function(event) {
        changes = true;
      });
    });
  </script>

  <div class="form-style-5">
    <legend>
      <span class="number">4</span> Search by Scholarship Requirements
    </legend>
    <form action="search3.php" method="post" oninput="amount1.value=rangeInput1.value; amount2.value=rangeInput2.value; amount3.value=rangeInput3.value;" target="_parent">
      <fieldset>
        Minimum SAT:
        <output for="rangeInput" name="amount1">0</output>
        <input id="rangeInput1" max="2400" min="0" name="satscore" required="" type="range" value="0">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input name="crm" type="checkbox" value="CR+M"> CR+M
        <input name="crm" type="checkbox" value="CR+M+W"> CR+M+W
        <br>
        <br> Minimum ACT:
        <output for="rangeInput" name="amount2">0</output>
        <input id="rangeInput2" max="36" min="0" name="actscore" required="" type="range" value="0">
        <br>
        <br> Minimum GPA:
        <output for="rangeInput" name="amount3">0</output>
        <input id="rangeInput3" max="4" min="0" name="gpascore" required="" type="range" value="0">
        <br>
      </fieldset>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="SEARCH">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Remember that this is only client side. Do your homeworks server side if it cares. I mean, the disable could be easily by-passed by any low-skilled guy.

Answer (score 0):

Add disabled property to submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="SEARCH" disabled>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#rangeInput1,#rangeInput2,#rangeInput3").on("change", function(){

    $("input[type='submit']).prop("disabled", "false");
}
```

Comment: Will setting the disabled property to false work? I thought disabled was boolean regardless of value - wouldn't it need to be removed? If not, I like this solution - short and clean. **Edit** - Although, I've just thought, what if the input is changed to a valid value, and then changed again to an invalid one? Wouldn't this then allow an invalid form to be submitted?

Comment: Then check whether any one of the three input range has a valid value after changing..If yes means remove the disabled property.